# Как получить размер матрицы и её элементы от пользователя?

Tags: c++

Как мне сделать так, чтобы размер матрицы и значение её элементов я вводил сам (то есть динамически)?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {

    int **matr;
    int rows;
    int cols;
public:


    int *operator[](int k) {
        return matr[k];
    }

    Matrix operator+(Matrix obj) {
        Matrix tmp(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                tmp[i][j] = matr[i][j] + obj[i][j];
        return tmp;
    }

    Matrix operator*(Matrix obj) {
        Matrix tmp(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    tmp[i][j] += matr[i][k] * obj[k][j];
        return tmp;
    }


    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                printf("%3d", matr[i][j]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


};
```

Comment: Добавить в конструктор данного класса считывание с консоли размеров матрицы и её элементов. А после в цикле проинициализировать значения. Что-то в роде cin>>n (считывание с консоли числа и запись его в параметр n)

Answer (score 3):

1. Добавить конструктор, который будет создавать матрицу указанного размера

   ```
   Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
     this.rows = rows;
     this.cols = cols;
     this.matr = new int*[rows];
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       this.matr[i] = new int[cols];
   }
   ```
2. Добавить деструктор, который будет уничтожать созданную матрицу

   ```
   ~Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
     for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
       delete [] this.matr[i];
     delete [] this.matr;
   }
   ```
3. И добавить конструктор копирования. Просто во избежание

   ```
   Matrix(Matrix &matrix) {
     this.rows = matrix.rows;
     this.cols = matrix.cols;
     this.matr = new int*[rows];
     for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
       this.matr[i] = new int[cols];
       for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
         this.matr[i][j] = matrix.matr[i][j];
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: А как заполнит матрицу?

Comment: @JekaX-Ray Ну это уже вы сами должны озаботится методами установки и чтения значений. Сейчас то вы как-то ее заполняете?

Comment: @JekaX-Ray и оператор `[]` у вас переопределен. Так и пишите `Matrix m(5, 5); m[0][1] = 2`

Comment: И как вы собираетесь компилировать присвоение типа массив  int(*)[]  указателью на указатель:  this.matr = new int[rows][cols]; ?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Спасибо за замечание. Исправил код

Comment: Рад быть полезен, за исправление плюс